# PHP Facebook SDK - check if user liked a fanpage

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to check if user liked a fanpage.

Here is my code:

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => APP_ID,
        'secret' => APP_SECRET,
        'cookie' => true,
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if (!$user)
    {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope' => 'user_likes'
        ));
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            $likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes/".$fanpage_id);
```

And my problem - Facebook doesn't give me in a response facebook pages id. I don't know why. When I try to accept a permissions (as user), I can accept only publish informations about me. I can't accept permission "user_likes" because I can't see this permission in text information while I'm accepting a permissions.

Anyone can't help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit Your app to Facebook for approval for anything more than public profile. Go to Your app settings, status and review section. And click big "Start a Submission" button. Then select `user_likes` object and submit Your app for approval.

[image]

Comment: “Like Gating” is not allowed by Facebook any more, and therefor for the purpose of checking whether the user likes a single specific page, you will not get the usage of `user_likes` permission granted in review. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_likes

Answer (score -1):

First of you have to registered or submit your app on facebook developer site. [Click here for facebook developer link](https://developers.facebook.com/)